# EditText fields not clearing when focus is changed

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I've got two EditText fields and a button,

```
EditText topNumericInputField; // Top text field
EditText bottomNumericInputField; // Bottom text field
Button clearButton; // Regular Button
```

I'm trying to clear the text that's in them when I change focus, my onClick method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.topInputField:
            clearTextBoxes();
            break;
        case R.id.bottomNumericInputField:
            clearTextBoxes();
            break;
        case R.id.clearButton:
            clearTextBoxes();
            break;
        }
}
private void clearTextBoxes() {
    topNumericInputField.getText().clear();
    bottomNumericInputField.getText().clear();
}
```

Now, it clears both fields fine with either:

a) The field I click on already has focus

or

b) I click the clear button

If I change focus from the top field to the bottom field, it gets focus, then I need to click it one more time.

I'm not sure exactly what's happening, but I'm sure it's related to something that keeps coming up in the LogCat log, every time I change focus two lines appear:

```
Tag: IInputConnectionWrapper Text: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
Tag: IInputConnectionWrapper Text: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

I've tried searching SO and I've seen some submissions that are similar, but none seem to really be what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't understand what you want. You want to clear editText when they get focus?

Comment: Yes, I want to clear the both fields when either of them is clicked. Right now, it only works when clicking on the field that already has focus. I also want to clear them when the other field is clicked.

Comment: you can override `onFocusChange()` to catch the focus change event. and editText.setText("") in that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is not with setting text but problem lies in capturing wrong event.

As you said you want to clear edittext when focus is changed, then you should override `onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasfocus)` to capture that event. You need to implement `FocusChangeListener`.

```
   edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean focus) {
            if (focus) {
                ((EditText)v).setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```

A simple implementation should look like above. [Refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) for detailed information

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text null.

```
topNumericInputField.setText("");
bottomNumericInputField.setText("");
```

Comment: I have tried both:


    topNumericInputField.setText("");
    bottomNumericInputField.setText("");


and


    topNumericInputField.setText(null);
    bottomNumericInputField.setText(null);

Comment: what's the error getting when setText null declare? @Steven

Comment: There's no error, other than the LogCat output, then I can click it again and it clears.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clear your Text by:

```
 topNumericInputField.setText("");
 bottomNumericInputField.setText("");
```